# Como definir funções advérbio (ou decorator)?

Tags: c++, c++11

Em C++11 como posso escrever uma função que:

- Recebe uma função `fun` como argumento
- Retorna uma nova função com a mesma assinatura que a função `fun` recebida e executa-a repassando os seu argumentos p/ `fun`.

Em R esse tipo de função é conhecido como ['funções advérbio'](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/faq-adverbs-export.html) em Python é comum encontrá-las como ['decorators'](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#examples)

Com C++14 consegui fazer algo do tipo:

```
auto adverb = [](const auto& f) {
  return [&](auto ... params) {
    std::cout << "Calling adverb code" << std::endl;
    return f(params...);
  };
};
```

Mas isso usa [*generic lambda expression*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) que aparentemente é feature a partir do C++14.

Comment: Fiz esse [exemplo em C++11](https://ideone.com/fwKKKV) mas não é tão flexível quanto a sua sua versão em C++14. Antes de escrever uma resposta precisava saber se o meu exemplo se adequa as suas necessidades.

Comment: Acho que não, é importante para mim que a assinatura da função nova seja a mesma da função que está sendo envelopada.

Comment: Mas a assinatura é a mesma, é decorador. Não entendi a observação, poderia ser mais claro?

Comment: Foi mal, não fui claro o suficiente. O que preciso é que a função retornada tenha a mesma assinatura independente da função que for passada p/ a função decoradora. No caso desse exemplo, só funcionaria se a função que está sendo passada tivesse `string` como único argumento.

Comment: Entendi. e justamente essa a falta de flexibilidade a que me refiro no [primeiro comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/540358/como-definir-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-adv%c3%a9rbio-ou-decorator?noredirect=1#comment971611_540358). Vou pesquisar mais, mas acho que não será possível usar de parâmetros variádicos, ou algo no gênero, com decoradores em C++11, só a partir do C++14

Comment: Sou leigo no assunto, uso C++ de "forma simples", então talvez eu não tenha entendido a necessidade, mas me parece que o que você deseja seja o [template  parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Comment: Acredito que sim, mas também não sei fazer :(

Answer (score -5):

Oi!

Uma declaração de função mínima consiste no tipo de retorno, nome da função e lista de parâmetros (que pode estar vazio), juntamente com palavras-chave opcionais que fornecem instruções adicionais ao compilador. O exemplo a seguir é uma declaração de função:

```
int sum(int a, int b);
```

Uma definição de função consiste em uma declaração, mais o corpo, que é todo o código entre as chaves:

```
    int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

As partes necessárias de uma declaração de função são:

O tipo de retorno, que especifica o tipo do valor que a função retorna, ou void se nenhum valor for retornado. No C++ 11, auto é um tipo de retorno válido que instrui o compilador a inferir o tipo da instrução return. No C++ 14, decltype(auto) também é permitido. Para obter mais informações, consulte dedução de tipo em tipos de retorno abaixo.

O nome da função, que deve começar com uma letra ou sublinhado e não pode conter espaços. Em geral, os sublinhados à esquerda nos nomes de função de biblioteca padrão indicam funções de membro privado ou funções não-membro que não se destinam ao uso pelo seu código.

A lista de parâmetros, uma chave delimitada, um conjunto separado por vírgulas de zero ou mais parâmetros que especificam o tipo e, opcionalmente, um nome local pelo qual os valores podem ser acessados dentro do corpo da função.

As partes opcionais de uma declaração de função são:

constexpr, que indica que o valor de retorno da função é um valor constante que pode ser calculado em tempo de compilação.

```
    constexpr float exp(float x, int n)
{
    return n == 0 ? 1 :
        n % 2 == 0 ? exp(x * x, n / 2) :
        exp(x * x, (n - 1) / 2) * x;
};
```

Sua especificação de vinculação extern ou static .

```
extern "C" int printf( const char *fmt, ... );
```

inline, que instrui o compilador a substituir cada chamada à função pelo próprio código de função. o inalinhamento pode ajudar o desempenho em cenários em que uma função é executada rapidamente e é invocada repetidamente em uma seção de código crítica de desempenho.

```
    inline double Account::GetBalance()
{
    return balance;
}
```

Uma noexcept expressão, que especifica se a função pode ou não gerar uma exceção. No exemplo a seguir, a função não lançará uma exceção se a is_pod expressão for avaliada como true .

```
  #include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
T copy_object(T& obj) noexcept(std::is_pod<T>) {...}
```

(Somente funções de membro) Os qualificadores CV, que especificam se a função é const ou volatile .

(Somente funções de membro) virtual , override ou final . virtual Especifica que uma função pode ser substituída em uma classe derivada. override significa que uma função em uma classe derivada está substituindo uma função virtual. final significa que uma função não pode ser substituída em nenhuma classe derivada adicional. Para obter mais informações, consulte funções virtuais.

(somente funções de membro) static aplicado a uma função de membro significa que a função não está associada a nenhuma instância de objeto da classe.

(Somente funções membro não estáticas) O qualificador de referência, que especifica para o compilador qual sobrecarga de uma função escolher quando o parâmetro de objeto implícito ( *this ) é uma referência rvalue versus uma referência lvalue. Para obter mais informações, consulte sobrecarga de função.

Answer (score -5):

No C++14, você pode usar para instruir o compilador a inferir o tipo de retorno do corpo da função sem precisar fornecer um tipo auto de retorno à parte final. Observe que auto sempre deduz a um retorno por valor. Use auto&& para instruir o compilador a deduzir uma referência.

Neste exemplo, será deduzido como uma cópia de valor não auto const da soma de lhs e rhs.

```
 template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
auto Add2(const Lhs& lhs, const Rhs& rhs)
{
    return lhs + rhs; //returns a non-const object by value
}
```

Observe que auto não preserva a const-ness do tipo que ele deduz. Para funções de encaminhamento cujo valor de retorno precisa preservar a const-ness ou ref-ness de seus argumentos, você pode usar a palavra-chave , que usa as regras de inferência de tipo e preserva todas as informações de decltype(auto)decltype tipo. decltype(auto) pode ser usado como um valor de retorno comum no lado esquerdo ou como um valor de retorno à direita.

Comment: Dona, a senhora não entendeu a pergunta. O Autor da pergunta criou um decorador. Decorator é um padrão estrutural que permite adicionar novos comportamentos aos objetos dinamicamente, colocando-os dentro de objetos wrapper especiais. Esse decorator foi escrito em C++14 e autor da pergunta quer o mesmo só que escrito em C++11, só que em C++11 só possível implementar um padrão menos flexível que o obtido com C++14, como [nesse código](https://ideone.com/fwKKKV)

Comment: Só para esclarecer. O Stack Overflow não é site de ajuda, não é rede de ensino, não é rede social, não é forum, não site de dicas. Somos um site de perguntas e respostas técnicas sobre linguagens de programação.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).